# Encrypted values being changed to question marks in request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am receiving an ID that is encrypted from the backend and I can see in the response it is coming without any question marks. But when passing this value in a request, I see some values are being changed. We are simply taking this value and passing it. Why would this be?

Example:

Getting from backend... ID = 7$ĄrÂŬÛ,ŕ4Ŀ+

While passing to another service... ID = 7$?rÂ?Û,?4?+

Edit: a few things to note

1. this is all happening within an iFrame
2. on page load, initial value is held in redux as an empty string ('')
3. issue does not happen when characters from the extended ascii table are not there, but only some ascii characters are changing to ?

Comment: Can you make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? What string do you start with, how do you take this value and pass it? And is the value with question marks only observed in another service, or also in the browser network requests tab?

Comment: Could be an issue if part/all of the original data is meant to be binary, or could be an issue if the incoming characters are in one charset, and the outgoing in another -- edit -- rereading your question, if the incoming characters are encrypted, my understanding is that the "string" is actually binary, and you are probably not reading it in nor sending it back out correctly. One possible solution is to use base64 encoding on both sides

Comment: If anyone else is facing this issue: instead of adding the encrypted value to the redux store, I added it to a global variable and passed it from there. It seems renderToString from react-dom manipulates some encrypted values.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without any code to see what's really happening, I have a few guesses on what *could* be going on.

- If the text is still encrypted or it's partially encrypted, then there won't actually be any character to display because it's in an encrypted binary format.

  > **Make sure the encrypted text is being *fully* decrypted.**

###### Character Support

- If you are viewing the encrypted text in a terminal, it may not be able to display the characters correctly, (as those specific characters are only supported in
  [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode),
  and not in
  [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)).

  > **Try outputting the text to a file.**
- If you are sending the request in a URL, the URL can only take certain characters without special formatting, only a subset (64) of the characters from the ASCII character set can be used.

  > Make sure it's being encoded (and decoded) with
  > [base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64)
  > for
  > [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)s
  > and
  > [forms](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm).